# Craft 3 admin panel only accessible when web/cpresources is exectuable for everyone

Tags: craft3, permissions, configuration

I’m trying to move a local Craft 3 site to a local server (hosted on 1&1).

The website itself runs fine, but for some reason I can only access the admin panel when the `web/cpresources` folder has permissions set to `777`, which I obviously don’t want. (**EDIT**: It also seems to work with `755`, but the folder probably shouldn't be executable by everone, right?)

All other folders where Craft needs write access are set to `744`, as per the install instructions, and as long as `web/cpresoures` are `755`, everything else seems to work fine.

Does anyone have an idea what can be the issue and a possible solution here?

Unfortunately I don’t know which user PHP runs under, but as a standard web hosting setup, I would guess it should be able to write to the file system without open access for everyone, and again everything else seems to be working like normal.

**UPDATE**:

It only

I managed to get the user by running this code:

```
$username = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];
$echo $username;
```

The reported user is the same as my account, meaning php should run as the same user that owns the files.

Comment: You need to determine the user/group php runs as, because that's what needs write perms for the web/cpresources folder. More here: https://nystudio107.com/blog/hardening-craft-cms-permissions

Comment: Yes, I realise that. Unfortunately I can't really determine what the php user runs as, or what group it's in, as I'm on a shared hosting with no access to the php installation itself. But I've had a running version of Craft 2 on the same server for at least a year, and it has been writing files without any problems (assets, updates, etc.)

Comment: `phpinfo()` should tell you that

Comment: Hm, does phpinfo() tell you the user it runs as on the server? I can't find it anywhere there at least.

Comment: It's not in phpinfo(), but I managed to find the user via posix_geteuid() and posix_getpwuid(). But it actually reports that it's running under the same user as the owner of the files (basically my account).